# What is $f(y) \ge f(x) + \left<\nabla f(x), y-x\right>$ meaning in nonlinear optimization?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis, nonlinear-optimization

I'm learning nonlinear optimization and encounter a definition as follows:
 $f$ is convex if and only if for all $x$ and $y$, $f(y) \ge f(x) + \left<\nabla f(x), y-x\right>$

Are x and y both vectors? Is $\left<\nabla f(x), y-x\right>$ a number(dot product)? Is there any intuitive explanation behind this formula? Because I feel this formula is kind of wired and hard to connect it to the original definition of convex.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome Math.SE! Take the [tour](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour) to get familiar with this site. Mathematical expressions and equations can be [formatted](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) using $\LaTeX$ syntax.

Comment: I think it is important to point out that this definition is _not correct_. After all, there are many convex functions that are _not differentiable_, so the "only if" cannot apply. A simple modification is to say that a _differentiable_ function $f$ is convex if and only if...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is best described by drawing a picture in two dimensions (the idea generalizes to the multidimensional case). The following plot is courtesy of: *Boyd, Stephen, and Lieven Vandenberghe. Convex optimization. Cambridge university press, 2004*

[image]

The idea is that $f(x) + \nabla f(x)^T (y-x)$ defines a tangent line (plane, in the multidimensional case) at the point $(x,f(x))$ parameterized by the variable $y$. As can be seen from the above plot, the function $f(y)$ lies *above* $f(x) + \nabla f(x)^T (y-x)$ for all $y$. If this test holds for every point along the graph, that is for every $(x,f(x))$, then the function $f$ is convex.